# Error when mapping dimension to fact table

Tags: iccube

I'm trying to deploy a schema containing a Cube with a fact table where I mapped a date dimension to a date field. I have also a dimension `ComptaCompte` representing bank accounts linked to the corresponding field.

My mapping to the date is working fine and the results are as expected. 
However, I have an error when I set the second mapping :

`Data table 'ComptaEcritureNew', line '80618' : Processing facts 'Cube.Ecriture', no member found for key '622003' in dimension 'ComptaCompte' and level 'ComptaCompteNum' - fact key column(s) = 'numCompte'`

I checked the content of my dimension and the account `622003` is present as well as in the table used in the fact table.

Where does the problem come from? Could it be a problem of memory?

Comment: key 622003 is missing in the ComptaCompteNum level (looks as an account). A quick fix is adding 'unknown' members where all id's not found are put, but it's an awful idea for producion.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the unknown members and it works. Now the question is how to do it properly for production?

Comment: You need to add the account number with key 6222003 when building the Compta level

Comment: I don't understand because when I display the levels by doing : `Select
        [Measures].allMembers on 0,
       [ComptaCompteNum].[ComptaCompteNum].[ComptaCompteNum].members on 1
    From
        [Cube]` I see that there is the account 622003. (It's normal if I changed the name from ComptaCompte to ComptaCompteNum, that's just a detail)

Comment: If it's a string it might be a special character or another UTF8 code for the same one, if it's an int we're missing something (you'll have to contact support)

Comment: It was indeed a problem of type, my field was a VARCHAR in the database and for no reason for some accounts, such as '622003', there is a space at the end... Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of type, my account field was a VARCHAR in the database and sometimes spaces were added to the number. I converted the output type to Integer through the table importation interface of icCube. The mapping works fine now.